# Deezer sdk sample player fails to get stream token attribute to launch playback

Tags: android, deezer

I can't launch the playback of a track, even from the sample app. Something goes wrong with the stream token I get from Deezer (seems missing!). Strange thing since I use the same Application ID for iOS version and I can play it fine, and I can get my playlists fine...
Any ideas?

EDIT

Seems like Deezer Application ID accepts only one platform. Odd since the dev tools allow you to fill both platforms. Create a new app especially for Android to get another Application ID solved the problem.

Comment: hello i am using deezer player module but can't find information on using the player. Can you help me please thanks